# Have any security vendors developed any Bitcoin Cross Domain Solutions (CDS) implementions yet?

Tags: transactions, security, protocol

Such technology (deep packet inspection firewall on steroids), which is typically on the US ITAR Export Control List (having EAL4+ Common Criteria ratings), should be very high on the Christmas List for all Exchanges?  Was interested in knowing the existing list of vendors in this market space. It sounds like this technology is sorely needed to plug the gaping security holes that we hear about in the news...

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by Cross Domain Solutions. All you need to do is be part of the global blockchain and you're plugged in. What else is needed?

Comment: A CDS is a guard that is integrated at the perimeter of a private network to provide substantial assurances the private network's integrity or confidentiality is not being compromised. See Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_%28information_security%29.  The CNSS definition of a CDS is "A form of a controlled interface that provides the ability to manually and/or automatically access and/or transfer information between different security domains." Defense firms such as RTCS, LMC, NGC sell them.  This technology could be adapted to support the Bitcoin Protocol.

Comment: Most all BTC Exchanges can't claim to have exercised "Due Diligence" or "Due Care" until they have investigated and applied CDS concepts or technologies to their network's perimeters.

Comment: Are you asking whether there's a CDS for the Bitcoin protocol, or whether there's a CDS aimed at Bitcoin exchanges?